# yum update on cent OS in a restricted network

Tags: centos7, yum

I have a situation where I have CentOS 7.5 installed on my VM from iso image. My server is not connected over internet. Now, I want to update the packages from centOS site but when I execute **yum update** , it fails with below error -

```
Error- https://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 
14] curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 2a00:1768:1001:48::10: Network is     unreachable"
Trying other mirror.
```

I have added the IP for mirror.centos.org in firewall rules. But problem is the IP keeps changing each time I try to do nslookup.

```
[root@763729-mars-oms-docker-registry yum.repos.d]# curl -v https://mirror.centos.org
* About to connect() to mirror.centos.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 185.50.225.30...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 2a05:b80:0:118::10...
* Failed to connect to 2a05:b80:0:118::10: Network is unreachable
* Failed connect to mirror.centos.org:443; Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2a05:b80:0:118::10: Network is unreachable
[root@763729-mars-oms-docker-registry yum.repos.d]# nslookup mirror.centos.org
Server:         83.138.151.80
Address:        83.138.151.80#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mirror.centos.org
Address: 195.154.220.72

[root@763729-mars-oms-docker-registry yum.repos.d]# nslookup mirror.centos.org
Server:         83.138.151.80
Address:        83.138.151.80#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mirror.centos.org
Address: 77.247.178.5

[root@763729-mars-oms-docker-registry yum.repos.d]# curl -v https://mirror.centos.org
* About to connect() to mirror.centos.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 109.228.54.129...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 2a02:2658:1056:0:222:19ff:fed6:7c9a...
* Failed to connect to 2a02:2658:1056:0:222:19ff:fed6:7c9a: Network is unreachable
* Failed connect to mirror.centos.org:443; Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2a02:2658:1056:0:222:19ff:fed6:7c9a: Network is unreachable
```

As firewall rules are not managed by us, we have to request our cloud provider to perform the changes each time if any change is to be performed. So, we have asked to implement dynamic ACL for this url. But it would take some time from their side to implement as they work outside our timezone, so I have to wait for next day.

But, is there a static IP for cent OS mirror repos, which I can refer and add it once to work around this. Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved by adding the nearest mirror site in baseurl and replacing mirror.centos.org. And adding the mirror site IP in firewall rule.